# How to start an ui from background code with flutter and alarmManager?

Tags: dart, flutter, alarmmanager

I use AlarmManager to run code in background code but. I need to start a UI  (like call a notification or ring the smartphone) in this code. I want to know how to do that? I know how to run the background taks but not how to start a UI.

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:relax/pages/intro.dart';
import 'package:relax/pages/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';

void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}

void main() async {
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  runApp(new MyApp());
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 15), helloAlarmID, printHello);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(title: 'Flutter Demo', initialRoute: '/', routes: 
   {
    '/': (context) => SplashScreen(),
    '/intro': (context) => IntroPage(),
   });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) (Medium article [here](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)), background Isolates in Flutter have a headless FlutterNativeView, so you'll never be able to draw anything from a background Isolate. The geofencing example shows two options:

1. Have your main Isolate register a SendPort with the IsolateNameServer. See example [here](https://github.com/bkonyi/FlutterGeofencing/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart). This is likely worthless in practice because the SendPort will be destroyed when the Activity is killed after any meaningful amount of time in the background (or if the user explicitly closes it).
2. Have the background Isolate show a notification. See example [here](https://github.com/bkonyi/FlutterGarageDoorOpener/blob/master/lib/src/geofence_trigger.dart). FlutterLocalNotifications will launch your main/UI Isolate when the notification is interacted with. If the notification is dismissed, or you require something other than a notification at a precise alarm time, you may be out of luck for now.

Note that you essentially have zero reliable communication between the Isolates, so you'll have to be creative if you're relying on any shared data.

Final note, you'll probably want to upgrade to the latest version of Flutter (>=1.12) to resolve some plugin registration issues. Add the following to your Android manifest just below the main Activity:

```
<activity>
    ...
</activity>
<meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
```